# Creating multiple users in a public Organzation Unit

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create 1000 users starting with Student#20036764 and create 1000 users to a OU called public. I have a loop set up but when I run it in powershell, the users don't show up in under the OU.

Here is what I put into powershell:

```
for($i = 200284647; $i -lt 20028547; $i++) {
    New-ADUser -Name student$i -SamAccountName student$i -DisplayName "student$i" -Enabled $false -Path "OU=Public,,DC=company,DC=epl,DC=local"
}
```

Comment: Improved code readability; removed unrelated comments; added missing whitespace to code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be a typo. I see the OU path is having 2 consecutive commas. If the correct OU path is "OU=Public,DC=company,DC=epl,DC=local". Another typo in the $i comparison count. The updated command would be,

```
for($i = 200284647; $i -lt 200285647; $i++) { New-ADUser -Name student$i -SamAccountName student$i -DisplayName "student$i" -Enabled $false -Path "OU=Public,DC=company,DC=epl,DC=local" }
```

Cheers!..